# Create new bounded number data types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, numbers

I need to create a data type, that represents only the real numbers between 0 and 1. How would i go about that? Expected Behavior:

```
0 :: DataType        ===> DataType 0
(-1) :: DataType     ===> Error
```

Comment: You could write an `instance Num DataType` and define `fromInteger` so that it errors out on invalid values. I'm not sure if that's a good idea, but it's the only way to achieve your goal.

Comment: @chi I actually suspect a transcription error there, given that it's ascribing function types to literals.  Not impossible, but I suspect that it's actually about creating a function to behave in such a way.

Comment: @Carl I'm pretty sure the above `->` represents "evaluates to", not function arrow. My comment assumed that interpretation, otherwise the question makes no sense. I'm now replacing them with `==>` to avoid confusion.

Comment: Beyond `instance Num DataType`, for real numbers we would also need `instance Fractional DataType`, and define a partial `fromRational` to reject invalid numbers.

Comment: You might want to use something like [Liquid Haskell](https://ucsd-progsys.github.io/liquidhaskell-blog/), which provides support for dependent types on top of Haskell.

Comment: Have you considered using _smart constructors_. Might by a good idea here. https://wiki.haskell.org/Smart_constructors